# How to order results by custom value and then by _score

Tags: elasticsearch

My document looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  user: {
    name: "some_name", 
    role: "admin" // this can be "admin", "member" or "guest"
  }
  ...
}
```

I know how to search for documents and ordering results by `_score` however I would like to order matching records in this order:

1. admins (first)
2. members (second - after admins)
3. guests (last - after admins and members)

And I would like to use `_score` as a second ordering parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `_script` based scoring:

```
{
  "query": {
    // whatever
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": "if(doc['role'].value=='admin') return 1; else if(doc['role'].value=='member') return 2; else if(doc['role'].value=='guest') return 3;",
        "type": "number",
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

OR, if you don't mind and can do this, you can create a new field in your index where you place for each role a number - like I did in the script above. Then, in your queries you don't use scripting, but

```
"sort": [
    {
      "role_ID_field": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
```